# file_get_contents not working on my server but works fine anywhere else?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get json data using get_file_contents but I not getting anything back. I tried curl but no avail. Following is my code

```
$url = 'http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json,TRUE);
echo "<h2>" . $obj['value']['joke'] . "</h2>";
```

And tried using curl:

```
function get_content($URL) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$json = get_content('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<h2>" . $obj['value']['joke'] . "</h2>";
```

Both the code snippets works fine on the PHPfiddle. I checked `allow_url_fopen` property in php.ini, it is on.

Thanks

Comment: Add [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and see what actually fails.

Comment: It did that but page keep loading and in the end I get this message "Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server closed the connection without sending any data.

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.

Due to heavy load on the server, connections may be temporarily blocked from locations that fetch an unusually high number of pages.

We apologize for the inconvenience."

Comment: Are you sure this is no firewall issue? Can you ping the server on your own webserver?

Comment: I am using a web server to host the website. I don't see anyway to ping from there.